# Kotlin - Higher order functions and type mismatch

Tags: android, kotlin

Im just beginning to learn kotlin and am struggling to understand how the higher-order functions determine types, i am regularly seeing this kind of error

> Error: Type mismatch: inferred type is KFunction2 but (String) -> Unit was expected

The above error is caused by the following

```
class MyClass(private val valueChangeListener: MyValueChangeListener, public val storage: MyStorage): MySuperClass {

    fun saveValue(potentialValue: String) {
        super.processValue(potentialValue, MyClass::save)
    }

    fun save(value: String){

        storage.storeValue(value)
        valueChangeListener.onValueChanged(value)
    }
}
```

However if i use a Lambda all is solved

```
class MyClass(private val valueChangeListener: MyValueChangeListener, public val storage: MyStorage): MySuperClass {

    fun saveValue(potentialValue: String) {
        super.processValue(potentialValue, super.processValue(potentialValue, { value: String ->
            save(value)
        })
    }

    fun save(value: String){

        storage.storeValue(value)
        valueChangeListener.onValueChanged(value)
    }
}
```

MySuperClass

```
open class MySuperClass {

    private fun cleanseValue(value: String) : String {
        return value.toUpperCase().replace(" ", "").replace("-", "")
    }

    protected fun processValue(potentialValue: String, saveFunction: (String) -> Unit){
        saveFunction(cleanseValue(potentialValue))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MyClass::save` is a `KFunction2`, meaning it has two parameters. This is because this expression refers to the method of the class instead of referring to a method of the current instance that you have. This means that when you're calling it, you have to pass in a `MyClass` instance to call it on, as well as the `String` parameter. This makes it a `(MyClass, String) -> Unit` function, which causes the type mismatch.

For example, this is how you could call it:

```
class MyClass {

    fun test() {
        val s = MyClass::save
        s(this, "some value")
    }

    fun save(value: String) {
        // ...
    }

}
```

As for what you're looking for, Kotlin 1.1 introduced [bound callable references](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew11.html#bound-callable-references), which you can use to refer to a function of a specific instance of a class:

```
class MyClass(private val valueChangeListener: MyValueChangeListener, public val storage: MyStorage): MySuperClass() {

    fun saveValue(potentialValue: String) {
        super.processValue(potentialValue, this::save) // see here
    }

    fun save(value: String){
        storage.storeValue(value)
        valueChangeListener.onValueChanged(value)
    }

}
```

Comment: Ahh i see thank you very much, the ide quick fix is to include `MyClass` rather than `this` when referencing the method as just `::save`

Answer (score 2):

In Kotlin 1.1, you can use [member reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#function-references) to solve this problem:

```
fun saveValue(potentialValue: String) {
    super.processValue(potentialValue, this::save)
}
```

If you use Kotlin 1.0.X, use lambda:

```
fun saveValue(potentialValue: String) {
    super.processValue(potentialValue, (arg) -> save(arg))
}
```